# Is my usage of $O$ notation correct here? Series $\sum (n^{1/n}-1)$ and $\sum \log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

I have an exam on monday and I just want to make sure I am using this notation correctly. Is there any ways I can make this argument style more rigorous?

It seems a bit hand wavey using this notation instead of directly applying Taylor's theorem in each case. For example, I feel ok writing: $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{\cos^5(\theta)}{5!}x^5$  for some $\theta\in(0,x)$.

When I am writing $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)$ I am just copying other people who are successful and am not entirely sure what theorem I am quoting.

$\\$
$\\$

Here is how I did it for the first series, $\sum (n^{1/n}-1)$

We examine the terms $a_n=(n^{1/n}-1) =e^{\frac{1}{n}\log(n)}-1=(1+\frac{1}{n}\log(n)+O(\frac{1}{n^2}\log(n)^2))-1=\frac{1}{n}\log(n) +O(\frac{1}{n^2}\log(n)^2))\geq \frac{1}{n}$

for all positive $n$ which make the expression defined. Therefore it diverges by the comparison test.

The next series, $\sum \log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})$:

Examining the terms $a_n=\log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})=(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}+O(\frac{1}{n^3}))$

Now using the limit comparison test with $b_n=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$, we take the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})}{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}=\frac{1+O(\frac{1}{n^{3/2}})}{1}=1<+\infty$

Therefore, $\sum \log(1+\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}})$ converges by the limit comparison test.

I hope I at least have the correct conclusions for these series...

Any feedback is very welcomed and thanks in advance!

Comment: You can easily use Taylor series to prove $e^x\geq 1+x$ for all $x\geq 0$. This also shows that $x\geq \ln(1+x)$ for all $x\geq 0$. I think these should imply the conclusions you want.

Comment: For the first, you don't need the inequality for all positive $n$: comparison with $\frac{\log n}{n}$ will do just fine, for instance. (Your conclusions are correct.) Incidentally, with $O()$ or $o()$ (I personally prefer the latter), you are using Taylor's theorem [with the Peano form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).